sum column value(s) if previous values has same value with current value from the same table in mysql
I'm trying to query sum(qtyin - qtyout) as newbalance based on the same price and the same productid. Table must be order by id, productid and price and after that if they have value of price, sum(qtyin-qtyout).
Table - Stock



id
ProductID
QtyIn
QtyOut
Price




1
0100001
4
0
1500


2
0100002
15
0
2500


3
0100001
11
0
1500


4
0100003
15
0
3500


5
0100001
14
0
2000


6
0100001
10
0
1500


7
0100001

20
1500



I want the result to be like this



id
ProductID
balance
Price




1
0100001
5
1500


5
0100001
14
2000


2
0100002
15
2500


4
0100003
15
3500



I have try like this
SELECT id,productid, (@prevQty := sum(QtyIn-QtyOut)) as balance, (@prevPrice := Price) as Price, (@prevQty := if(@prevPrice != Price, 0, sum(QtyIn-QtyOut))) as newbalance  from stock as s group by productid,price ORDER by Productid,Id,Price;

but the result is not what I wanted

the id in the result is the min(id) in the query.

use this query:
 select min(id) as id, ProductID, sum(QtyIn - QtyOut) as balance, Price
    from
        Stock
    group by
        ProductID, Price
    order by
        id, ProductID, Price;

min(id) as id :  selects the smallest id.

thanks' Shila Mosammami. your answer is very useful

You are so welcome

I don't see what meaning ID has in the result, but how about:
SELECT Productid,
       SUM(QtyIn - QtyOut) as balance,
       Price
FROM stock AS s
GROUP BY Productid,
         Price
ORDER BY Productid,
         Price;


The table must be sorted by id, productid and price before being summed. id indicates that the data was input first.  For the results, the id sequence is no longer needed, only sorted by product id. Is that possible?

"sorted by id, productid and price before being summed"- why? What difference does it make? What does "id indicates that data was input first" mean?
